# Storing a popped character from stack in memory

Tags: assembly, armv7

I'm working on an Armv7 assemebly program that requires the user to type in characters, store them into memory, then push them onto the stack. After the 4th character is pushed, the program pops the last 2 characters, stores them into memory, then prints them out. I have the following code but I can't figure out how to store the popped characters into memory. Any suggestions?

```
.global _start
_start:

loop:
    add r4, #1          @increment the loop by 1
    cmp r4, #4          @compare r4 to the number 4
    bgt pop1            @branch if r4 is bigger than 4

    mov r7, #3          @read syscall
    mov r0, #0          @stdin file pointer
    mov r2, #2          @2 character, the character itself and the new line
    ldr r1, =string         @load the address of the input to r1
    swi 0

    ldrb r5, [r1]           @load the bit in address r1 to r4
    cmp r5, #'q'            @compare that character to the character q
    beq _exit           @branch if the character is q
    stmfd sp!, {r5}         @push the character to the stack
    bal loop            @branch back to the top of the loop
/*
nextline:
    mov r7, #4
    mov r0, #1
    mov r2, #1
    ldr r6, =newline
    swi 0 */
pop1:
    add r8, #1
    cmp r8, #2
    bgt loop
    ldmfd sp!, {r5}         @PROBLEMs
    str r5, [r9]
    @bal pop1
print:
    mov r7, #4
    mov r0, #1
    mov r2, #2
    ldr r1, =string
    swi 0

    @bal pop1

_exit:
    mov r7, #1
    swi 0



    .data
string:
    .space 2

newline:
    .ascii "\n"
store:
    .space 2
```

right now, the code gives a segmentation fault when it gets to str r5, [r9]

Comment: I am surprised that even assembles.  `str r5, =store` is meaningless. `ldr r0, =store; str r5, [r0]` should work better.

Comment: @Jester you're right, it does't assemble. I was just trying a bunch of different things to see what works

Comment: PS: Writing 4 bytes when you only reserved 2 doesn't sound like a terribly good idea either.

Comment: The updated code faults obviously because `r9` is never set so it contains zero or random garbage.

Comment: @Jester that makes sense. Thank you so much, you're a life saver!